# Set a size in between small and normalsize

Tags: latex, tex

I am using the listings package and the command to set the font size in a listing is:

```
\lstset{basicstyle = \small}
```

I would like to modify this to use a font size that is half way between \small and \normalsize. Something like this does not work:

```
\lstset{basicstyle = 0.5\small+0.5\normalsize}
```

Is there any way to set the font size as I want it?

Answer (score 6):

This depends on your document class setting. For example, `\small` under a `10pt` document class option is `9pt` and `\normalsize` is `10pt` (of course, because of the class option). See [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) for other sizes based on the `\documentclass`. Based on this, set your `basicstyle` to `9.5pt` (with an appropriate midway baseline skip) manually via `\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\selectfont`, or use the following automated calculation via `\smalltonormalsize` as a font switch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xfp}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\makeatletter
{\small % Capture font definitions of \small
\xdef\f@size@small{\f@size}
\xdef\f@baselineskip@small{\f@baselineskip}
\normalsize % Capture font definitions for \normalsize
\xdef\f@size@normalsize{\f@size}
\xdef\f@baselineskip@normalsize{\f@baselineskip}
}
% Define new \smalltonormalsize font size
\newcommand{\smalltonormalsize}{%
  \fontsize
    {\fpeval{(\f@size@small+\f@size@normalsize)/2}}
    {\fpeval{(\f@baselineskip@small+\f@baselineskip@normalsize)/2}}%
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily\small]
Hello world A
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily\smalltonormalsize]
Hello world B
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily\normalsize]
Hello world C
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ideally, I would like to have a way to do this that is independent of having to look up the document class setting each time I create a new document or if I modify the document class. But this is a relatively minor consideration.

Comment: @DavidS: I've updated the code to include an automated calculation of the midway point between `\small` and `\normalsize` as `\smalltonormalsize`.